# Load basic CSV data to D3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js

I have been trying to load some data from a CSV to in D3. The structure is:

```
variety, amount
a, 1
b, 3
c, 7
```

I am trying to get the amount data into an array and have been unsuccessful trying all the methods described in various tutorials and forum posts.

I have tried:

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    var dataset = console.log(data["amount"]);
});


var dataset = d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    dataset = console.log(data["amount"]);
});


d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    dataset = console.log(data.amount);
});


d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    var dataset = console.log(data);
});


d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
    var dataset = data);
});


d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
            return {amount: +data};
});

d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
            dataset = data.map(function(d) { return [+d["amount"], +d["variety"]];});
});
```

I apologize if some of these attempts are ridiculous, but I just started playing around with D3 today. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: can you paste your full html and js here? I guess you include the lib in the wrong order

Comment: I am just trying to get my data from a CSV to be the variable `dataset` in Scott Murray's example here: https://github.com/alignedleft/d3-book/blob/master/chapter_06/21_making_a_bar_chart_aligned.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is with the empty space after the comma. Because of the space, it is being treated as " amount" and not "amount". Also try consoling just data and not data['amount']. You will realise that it is an array of objects and not just a single object. So you will have to iterate over the array to get the amount.

```
d3.csv("data.csv", function(data) {
  console.log(data);
  var len = data.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    console.log(data[i].amount);
  }
});
```

Comment: this works in the console, but how can I save it as: `var dataset = ` ?

Comment: so i figured out how to set dataset:
        `d3.csv("/Users/jdesilvio/Dropbox/D3\ Dev/data.csv", function(data) {
                console.log(data);
                var len = data.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
                    dataset.push(Number(data[i].amount));
                }
            });` but when I load the script it doesn't render anything. In the console, the array prints though when I type `dataset`.

Comment: As I mentioned in the comment above, I'm using Scott Murray's example: https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alignedleft/d3-book/master/chapter_06/21_making_a_bar_chart_aligned.html

Comment: Can you console the dataset immediately after the amount is being pushed in the dataset. Also you program now needs to run inside of d3.csv because d3.csv is async. So if your program is outside of d3.csv, the program will get dataset as undefined.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar plnkr for you, please pay attention to the place where load the d3 lib.

```
<body>
  <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
  ...
```

[pnlkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/eUcWmuqV5RfuW4g3XF3K?p=preview)